# How to mock repository with PHPUnit?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I'm trying to test my repository. I made `BaseLegalRepository`

```
class BaseLegalRepository extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * @var LegalRepository
     */
    protected $repository;

    public function testAdd(): void
    {
        $legal = (new CreateLegalBuilder())->build();
        $this->repository->add($legal);
        $found = $this->repository->get($legal->getId());
        $this->assertEquals($legal->getId(), $found->getId());
        $this->assertEquals($legal->getName(), $found->getName());
        $this->assertEquals($legal->getAddress(), $found->getAddress());
    }
    public function testGet(): void
    {
        $this->repository->add($legal = (new CreateLegalBuilder())->build());
        $found = $this->repository->get($legal->getId());
        $this->assertNotNull($found);
        $this->assertEquals($legal->getId(), $found->getId());
    }
    public function testGetNotFound(): void
    {
        $this->expectException(NotFoundException::class);
        $this->repository->get(new Id(uniqid()));
    }
}
```

When I extend it with `MemoryLegalRepositoryTest`:

```
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->repository = new MemoryLegalRepository();
    }
```

It works fine. All tests passed.
When I extend it with `LegalMySQLRepositoryTest`:

```
 protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $repository = $this->getMockBuilder('App\Legal\Infrastructure\Persistence\MySQL\LegalMySQLRepository')
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->onlyMethods(['add','get'])
            ->getMock();
    }
```

I get an error:

```
1) App\Tests\Legal\Infrastructure\Persistence\LegalMySQLRepositoryTest::testAdd
Error: Call to a member function add() on null
```

I [read the docs](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.5/test-doubles.html) but I probably didn't understand how Mock works

`LegalMySQLRepository` works (I saved data with Controller)

How to mock my LegalMySQLRepository correctly?
And one more question is how to inject the test database into the test (in another test)? I'm using Symfony and Doctrine but just Dbal (not with ORM - Entities and repositories). How to inject `Connection` into  `protected function setUp(): void`?
In `LegalMySQLRepository` i can use

```
private Connection $connection;

    public function __construct(Connection $connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }
```

but i don't understand how to inject it in `setUp()` method.

**Updated**
An error when I use `$this->repository`

````
1) App\Tests\Legal\Infrastructure\Persistence\LegalMySQLRepositoryTest::testAdd
Mock_ID_d69f21b7 Object &000000003fc7a3290000000004bcfb32 (
    '__phpunit_originalObject' => null
    '__phpunit_returnValueGeneration' => true
    '__phpunit_invocationMocker' => null
) is not instance of expected class "App\Legal\Domain\VO\ID".
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-App\Legal\Domain\VO\ID Object &000000003fc7a2cb0000000004bcfb32 (
-    'id' => '1c5ed0cd-4755-4f01-b66e-d3289167f309'
+Mock_ID_d69f21b7 Object &000000003fc7a3290000000004bcfb32 (
+    '__phpunit_originalObject' => null
+    '__phpunit_returnValueGeneration' => true
+    '__phpunit_invocationMocker' => null
 )
```
````

Comment: If `$repository = $this->getMockBuilder(` for your one that fails, should you be using `$this->repository` to store the result for use later?

Comment: Yes of course. Need to use `$this->repository`) Thanks. But i got another error (i refreshed my question)

Comment: it is *completely unclear* what you're actually trying to test in your test. as far as I can tell, you're testing if a mock repository returns an object you gave it. What are you trying to achieve with that? oO also changing the focus of the question in a major way is bad form.